# DISCORD.PY Ticket System error how to fix

Tags: discord.py

i learned how to make a ticket system from some github user and I implemented the same code it worked perfectly like creating a ticket channel but there is a problem when i clicked the reaction to close my ticket and to delete my ticket channel which was created by the bot but it didn't delete the channel

here is the code:

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if 'React with :ticket: to create a ticket' in reaction.message.embeds[0].description and reaction.emoji == '' and not user.bot:
      role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="@everyone")
      chan = await user.guild.create_text_channel(name=f'ticket - {user}')
      await chan.set_permissions(role, send_messages=False, read_messages=False, add_reactions=False, embed_links=False, attach_files=False, read_message_history=False, external_emojis=False)
      await chan.set_permissions(user, send_messages=True, read_messages=True, add_reactions=True, embed_links=True, attach_files=True, read_message_history=True, external_emojis=True)
      embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Ticket",
        description="React with :lock: to close a ticket",
        color=0x00FFFF
        )
      embed.set_footer(text="Ticket system")
      msg = await chan.send(embed=embed)
      await msg.add_reaction("")

    if 'React with :lock: to close a ticket' in reaction.message.embeds[0].description and reaction.emoji == '' and not user.bot:
        await channel.delete()


@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def ticket(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel = None):
    if channel==None:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Ticket",
            description="React with :ticket: to create a ticket",
            color=0
        )
        embed.set_footer(text="Ticket system")
        msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await msg.add_reaction("")

    else:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Ticket",
            description="React with :ticket: to create a ticket",
            color=0
        )
        embed.set_footer(text="Ticket system")

        msg = await channel.send(embed=embed)
        await msg.add_reaction("")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do `await channel.delete()` but you haven't defined `channel` variable. Replace it with `await reaction.message.channel.delete()`.

Also note that

```py
chan = await user.guild.create_text_channel(name=f'ticket - {user}')
await chan.set_permissions(role, send_messages=False, read_messages=False, add_reactions=False, embed_links=False, attach_files=False, read_message_history=False, external_emojis=False)
await chan.set_permissions(user, send_messages=True, read_messages=True, add_reactions=True, embed_links=True, attach_files=True, read_message_history=True, external_emojis=True)
```

is very slow and it isn't a good practice.
You can create channel with specific overwrites at once:

```py
overwrites = {
    role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
    user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(send_messages=True, read_messages=True, add_reactions=True, embed_links=True, attach_files=True, read_message_history=True, external_emojis=True)
}
chan = await user.guild.create_text_channel(name=f"ticket - {user}", overwrites=overwrites)
```

And you don't need to set up other permissions for `role` if `read_messages=False`.

Comment: thx very much it worked